# Issue with determining prime number [Java]

Tags: java

I heard you can determine if a number is prime by checking if it is divisible by 2 or 3 and then either 6k + 1 or 6k - 1 (17 --> 6(3) - 1)

When I try this though, it says 1125 is a prime number.  It evaluates the num - 1%6 to be true in the if statement but not in the print function.  The syntax is the same as the num + 1 %6 if statement so I'm not sure what is going on.

```
boolean prime = false;
    if(num%2 != 0){
        if(num%3 != 0){
            if(((num+1)%6) == 0)
                prime = true;
            if(((num-1)%6) == 0)
                prime = true;
            System.out.print((1124%6 == 0));
        }
    }
```

Comment: `6k + 1 or 6k - 1 (17 > 6(3) - 1)` ?typo 3 = k? I doubt this assumption is correct anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code never gets past `(num % 3 != 0)` on 1125 because 1125 is evenly divisible by 3.  So, on that number, your System.out is never executed.

Here, I adjusted your code a bit:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int num = 2; num < 2000; num++) {
      boolean prime = false;
      if (num % 2 != 0) {
        if (num % 3 != 0) {
          if (((num + 1) % 6) == 0) prime = true;
          if (((num - 1) % 6) == 0) prime = true;
        }
      }
      System.out.println(num + " prime? " + prime);
    }
  }
```

Sample output:

```
1124 prime? false
1125 prime? false
1126 prime? false
1127 prime? true
```

1127 is not prime (7 * 161) so the algorithm doesn't work.  Although I suspect it's pretty good at finding prime candidates.